# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y=f(x)$ at $ (\frac{\pi}{2},1)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\sin^3(x)$.

a) The derivative that I found is $3 \sin^2(x) \cos(x)$.

I cannot find the equation to the curve. I have tried substituting the values of the formula $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, but none of my answers come out to be correct.

Comment: Your method is right so there must be something wrong with your working.  Please post your working so that someone can tell you where you went astray.

Comment: The answer that I always get (and try simplifying, which is where my error comes from) is y = 3x sin^2(x) cos(x) - (3pi)/(2) sin^2(x) cos(x) + 1

Comment: Looks like you didn't substitute $x=\frac\pi2$ into the gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your work $f'(x)=3\sin^2x\cos x$.  Thus $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=3\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2})\cos (\frac{\pi}{2})=0.$
Then your tangent line is

$y-1=0(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$. That is $y=1$.