# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve y=f(x) at the point (1,6)

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{2x^2+4x+30}$

The derivative of the function is $(4x+4) /\sqrt{(2(2x^2+4x+30)}$

I have used the formula $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, but I do not know how to simplify the equation.

Comment: Next time you might consider waiting longer before posting another exercise that you’re having problems with. You made essentially the same error here as you did in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2932564/265466).

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x)=\sqrt{2x^2+4x+30}$ and the point is $(1,6)$

Now $f^{\prime}(x)=\dfrac{2x+2}{\sqrt{2x^2+4x+30}}$

Now calculate the slope at $(1,6)$ which is $\dfrac{2\cdot1+2}{\sqrt{2(1)^2+4\cdot1+30}}=\dfrac{2}{3}$

Now the line with slope $m=\dfrac23$ passing through $(1,6)$ is $\dfrac23x+\dfrac{16}{3}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! It didn't even occur to me to substitute the x values. I feel like I should have know that …